# Alterar imagem com hover CSS

Tags: html, css, css-hover

Tenho duas imagens no html e estão as duas no mesmo lugar da página. O que eu quero fazer é tocar as imagens com hover. Escondi uma imagem com display:none e quando hover o display fica block, mas não está a resultar. Alguma ideia?

```css
.left_corpo .restaurantes{
        position: absolute;
        height: 30%;
        width: 17%;
        margin-left: 15%;
        margin-top: 12%;
        cursor: pointer;
}
.left_corpo .restaurantes_hover{
        position: absolute;
        height: 30%;
        width: 17%;
        margin-left: 15%;
        padding-top: 12%;
        display: none;
        cursor: pointer;
}
.restaurantes:hover + .restaurantes_hover {
        display: block;
}
.restaurantes_hover:hover{
        display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="left_corpo">
        <div class="restaurantes">
          <img src="<?php echo $restaurantes; ?>" onclick="abrirlayer('layer_restaurantes')">
        </div>
        <div class="restaurantes_hover">
          <img src="<?php echo $restaurantes_hover; ?>" onclick="abrirlayer('layer_restaurantes')">
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: SOLVED! OBRIGADO A TODOS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça com a propriedade opacity, e aproveite o z-index, assim escusa de fazer alguma coisa na imagem da `.restaurantes_hover`:

```
.left_corpo .restaurantes{
        position: absolute;
        height: 30%;
        opacity: 1;
        z-index:1;
        width: 17%;
        margin-left: 15%;
        margin-top: 12%;
        cursor: pointer;
}
.left_corpo .restaurantes_hover{
        position: absolute;
        height: 30%;
        width: 17%;
        margin-left: 15%;
        padding-top: 12%;
        cursor: pointer;
}
.restaurantes:hover {
        opacity:0;
}
```

Tem aqui um [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qfd7rq9z/1/) adequado à sua estrutura

Comment: Peço desculpa, apesar de ter considerado certa creio que assim ainda é melhor. Editei em cima com um exemplo

Answer (score 2):

Se está como `display:none` é como se não existisse, podes fazer com recurso a Javascript:

```js
function muda(){
  document.getElementById("imgRestaurante").src="<?php echo $restaurantes_hover; ?>";   
}
```

```css
.left_corpo .restaurantes{
        position: absolute;
        height: 30%;
        width: 17%;
        margin-left: 15%;
        margin-top: 12%;
        cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="left_corpo">
        <div class="restaurantes"><img onmouseover="muda();" id="imgRestaurante" src="<?php echo $restaurantes; ?>" onclick="abrirlayer('layer_restaurantes')"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza o `:hover` selector no parent element. Isto porque a DIV permanece para verificar se existe `:hover` ou não... Não podes aplicar um `:hover` na imagem diretamente se esta é escondida.

Exemplo:

```css
.img-box img.img-hover {
  display: none;
}
.img-box:hover img.img-default {
  display: none;
}
.img-box:hover img.img-hover {
  display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-box">
  <img class="img-default" src="http://placehold.it/332x300" />
  <img class="img-hover" src="http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" />
</div>
```

Puro HTML e CSS funciona em todos os browsers...

Comment: Assim, mesmo que passes ao lado da imagem ele muda...

Comment: Assim, mesmo que passes ao lado da imagem ele muda...

Comment: entao na div metes a CSS display: inline-block;

Answer (score -2):

Tente desta forma:

HTML

```
 <div class="left_corpo">
    <div class="restaurantes"><img  onclick="abrirlayer('layer_restaurantes')"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.restaurantes {
background-image: url(http://images.dailytech.com/nimage/G_is_For_Google_New_Logo_Thumb.png);
text-decoration: none;
background-size:50px;
width:50px;
height:50px;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
}

.restaurantes:hover
{
background-image: url(http://img.mynet.com/ha2/tayyip.jpg);
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```